# how to find average of 25 consecutive columns in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have used 25 columns in a Mysql database. I need to calculate average for each of the columns. There will be a null value which should not be included named as 99.

I used this code for column r1
How do I find new averages and store it in different variables up to r25 table?

```
$rat = $arr['r1'];
if ($rat != 99)
{
   $s = $rat = $s;
   $n = $n + 1;
   $avg = $s / $n;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
$sums = array();
$counts = array();
$avgs = array();
while($arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
  if($val!=99){
   $sums[$key] += $val;
   $counts[$key] += 1;
 }
}
foreach($sums as $key=>$val){
 $avgs = (($counts[$key]>0)?$sums[$key]/$counts[$key]:0);
}
```

Comment: The database I'm using is a rating database.There will be lot of null values in DB which will be replaced by value 99. I need to calculate average of those 25 tables on array variable.

Comment: That's what the line if($val!=99){ does, if the value is 99, it won't count it. If it's still null, you could just say if(!is_null($val))